# Cannot find name 'X'.ts(2304)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, asynchronous, axios

I am trying to make an API call and want to display the different types of currency for a country someone selects. I am getting the error "Cannot find name 'countryCode'.ts(2304)" in the Charting.ts file. I've got two files:

`useApplicationApi.ts`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { initAxiosInstance } from './utils';

export interface CountryCode {
  name: string;
  rate: number;
  symbol: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}
export interface CoinRoot {
  coins: Coin[];
}
export interface Coin {
  id: string;
  icon: string;
  name: string;
  symbol: string;
  rank: number;
  price: number;
  priceBtc: number;
  volume: number;
  marketCap: number;
  availableSupply: number;
  totalSupply: number;
  priceChange1h: number;
  priceChange1d: number;
  priceChange1w: number;
  websiteUrl: string;
  twitterUrl: string;
  exp: string[];
  contractAddress?: string;
  decimals?: number;
}

export const useApplicationApi = () => {
  const portalClient = initAxiosInstance();

  const portalClientCoin = axios.create({

    baseURL: 'https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1',

    responseType: 'json',

  });


  const getCountryCodes = async () => {
    const { data } = await portalClientCoin.get<CountryCode[]>('/fiats');

    return data;
  };


  // GET COINs - needs new interface called coin
  // need to accept a parameter called currencyCode
  // https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/coins?limit=5&currency=EUR (coins)

  const getCountryCoins = async (currencyCode: string) => {
    const { data } = await portalClientCoin.get<CoinRoot[]>(`coins?&currency=${currencyCode}`);

    return data;
  };

  return {
    getCountryCodes,
    getCountryCoins,
  };
};
```

and
`Charting.tsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, Select,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { CoinRoot, useApplicationApi } from '../../../services/api/hooks/useApplicationApi';

const Charting = () => {
  const { getCountryCodes } = useApplicationApi();
  const { getCountryCoins } = useApplicationApi();
  const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState<string>('USD');
  const [countryCodes, setCountryCodes] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [countryCoins, setCountryCoins] = useState<CoinRoot[]>([]);

  const getCountryCodeInfo = async () => {
    const codes = await getCountryCodes();
    setCountryCodes(codes.map((country) => country.name));
  };

  const getLocalCountryCoins = async (currencyCode: string) => {
    const currencyCoins = await getCountryCoins(currencyCode);
    setCountryCoins(currencyCoins);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountryCodeInfo();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getLocalCountryCoins(currencyCode);
  }, [countryCode]);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown; }>) => {
    setCountryCode(event.target.value as string);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ color: 'pink', backgroundColor: 'blue', marginBottom: 30 }}>
        {countryCode}
      </div>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={countryCode}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {countryCodes.map((cc, index) => <MenuItem key={`menu-item-${index}`} value={cc}>{cc}</MenuItem>)}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>

      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(countryCoins, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    </>
  );
};

export default Charting;
```

Also, do you have a link to a tutorial I can follow to practice API calls/async/await?

I have been struggling trying to understand API calls and I was following the errors I kept getting like "Expected an argument of 1 but got 0" but I'm not understanding the WHY behind it all.